# Micronaut unit testing : need clarification on @MicronautTest

Tags: java, unit-testing, micronaut

I am trying my hands on micronaut, I am facing some difficulty in understanding how to do unit tests.

I have a simple application with only one controller(which returns hello).
Now I want to test this endpoint. Coming from springboot I was expecting that micronaut has some runner class like `SpringRunner`, I could not find any. **Is there a runner class in micronaut for running tests?**

From the documentation [here](https://docs.micronaut.io/snapshot/guide/index.html#creatingClient) I see that I can test my rest endpoints using HTTPClient. I tried both the

1. Low level HttpClient
2. CompileTime HttpClient

Here is a snippet of the test classes I have

```
@MicronautTest
class HelloControllerSpec {
    @Inject
    EmbeddedServer server; 

    @Inject
    @Client("/")
    HttpClient client; 

    @Test
    void testHelloWorldResponse() {
          //client and server are null
           .........
    }
}
```

And

```
@MicronautTest 
public class HelloClientSpec  {

    @Inject
    HelloClient client; 

    @Test
    public void testHelloWorldResponse(){
        //client is null
   }
}
```

From what I observed, the annotation `@MicronautTest` doesn't seem to do anything. Its the same case with `@Inject` and `@Client`, all the fields are null when I run the test.  So I am wondering **what exactly does `@MicronautTest` do?**

The only way I could get it work is to start the server explicitly(`@Inject` on `EmbeddedServer` doesn't do anything) like this

```
server = ApplicationContext.run(EmbeddedServer.class);
helloClient = server.getApplicationContext().getBean(HelloClient.class);
```

Even with this, it starts a server instance. Which in not what I wanted. Because I do not want to start server for unit tests. Also I do not want to get the beans this way from application Contexts. **Whay doesn't `@Inject`, `@Client`, `@EmbeddedServer` work in my case, am I missing something here?**

In case of springboot, I could test only the weblayer separately(using mockmvc and springboottest), not starting the whole application context. **is there an equivalent in micronaut?**

I am using micronaut 1.0.2

Comment: "From what I observed, the annotation @MicronautTest doesn't seem to do anything." - It is definitely not the case that `@MicronautTest` doesn't do anything.  Your test looks like a JUnit test.  Do you have a dependency on `io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5` in your project?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown no i do not have that. I have `micronaut-test-core` and `junit 4`

Comment: The micronaut test library provides extensions for JUnit 5 and Spock.

Comment: You added the comment "I am using micronaut 1.0.2" but the docs you link (https://docs.micronaut.io/snapshot/guide/index.html#creatingClient) are to the latest snapshot docs.  You probably should be looking at the 1.0.2 docs which are at https://docs.micronaut.io/1.0.2/guide/index.html#creatingClient.  Separate from that, the docs for `@MicronautTest` are available at https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/1.1.1/guide/index.html which points out that we have support for Spock and JUnit 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who encounters this issue. Here are a few hints. This is what solved the issue in my case. Humble mention to Jeff Scott Brown, whose suggestions pushed me in the right direction.

1. Please check the micronaut version,
   I had micronaut `1.0.2` version installed through which I generated the app. But the documentation I was following was of latest version which is `1.2.3`
2. Please check which junit version you have in your pom or build file. If you generate the app with latest(1.2.3) you will have Junit-5 and Jupiter dependencies, If you are using older(1.0.2) versions, you will have Junit4.
   For the annotation `@MicronautTest` to work you need Junit5

Comment: "Annotations like Inject, Client are not available in 1.0.2 version." - That isn't true and isn't related to the originally reported issue.  Both of those annotations are available in 1.0.2 (though Inject isn't a Micronaut annotation, but is usable in Micronaut 1.0.2 and every other version of Micronaut).

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Agree Inject is not from micronaut.What I meant to say was Injecting EmbeddedServer with `@Inject`  will not work in 1.0.2. is that correct?

Comment: "What I meant to say was Injecting EmbeddedServer with @Inject will not work in 1.0.2. is that correct?" - No, that isn't correct.  The test at https://github.com/jeffbrown/micronaut102testinject/blob/54da67089cd4f6e578b0e34530e21d257f702fce/src/test/java/micronaut102testinject/DemoControllerTest.java is in a 1.0.2 app and that test passes.  It is impossible to say what is wrong without seeing a project which demonstrates the issue but my first guess is you are using 1.1.x of micronaut-test which is incompatible with Micronaut 1.0.2.